# Getting 404 on vs-mda-remote deploy

Tags: ios, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to run the blank default cordova app from VS2013 using the remote device target and I am getting the following output from the OSX-side:

```
Done with currentBuild. Checking for next build in queue.
GET /build/tasks/22365 200 1ms - 856b
GET /build/tasks/22365/log 200 3ms
GET /files/22365/cordovaApp/plugins/ios.json 200 2ms - 190b
Transferring result of build 22365 ...
Trasnferred build 22365
GET /build/22365/download 200 401ms
Deploy build 22365 ...
GET /build/22365/deploy 404 362ms - 16b
```

The local device target works fine - It will build successfully and transfer the .ipa back to my Windows iTunes without issues.

I am not sure what next steps to take. The build log does not indicate any errors (as I would expect) and I am not sure if there is some other resource I can look at to determine the reason for the 404.

**Update:**

I wiped out all traces of node/npm/vs-mda-remote/etc on the OSX build machine and reinstalled from scratch and now I am getting the following error in Visual Studio:

```
Error   3   Http 404: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -i /Users/[redacted]/remote-builds/builds/24447/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device/BlankCordovaApp1.ipa    BlankCordovaApp1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you wiped out everything, seems like you don’t have the libimobiledevice tools installed. Can you please try deleting ~/.vs-mda-remote. Once you do that, restarting vs-mda-remote, should ask you to install homebrew and libimobiledevice tools.

Comment: This did it. I also had to `brew update && brew upgrade` and reinstall vs-mda-remote as well as ideviceinstaller. On a clean OSX Yosemite install this probably would not have been an issue.